# Mapping port1 and port2 on windows mobile emulator does not work

Tags: windows, windows-mobile, serial-port, emulation

I am trying to connect three serial devices on a windows mobile 5.0 emulator in visual studio 2008, by mapping port0, port1 and port2 to com3, com4 and com5 of the host computer resp.

I have realised that port0 (com1 of emulator) works perfectly but port1 (com2 of emulator?) does not even exist and port2 (com3 of emulator?) presents errors. I used putty on the host and pocket putty on the emulator to check all that.

Is there any way of making this work? While developing I could work with just two serial ports and work around not having a third but only one port is a problem.